# how to animate back to defaults with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design

I'm using jQuery to apply element-level inline styles which will override the underlying css class style definitions.

All good so far, but then I want to un-do this, and to animate back to the properties that would be defined by the CSS rules, removing the element's inline style.

An [oft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619747/reverting-jquery-animations-back-to-original-css-states) [offered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854877/jquery-animating-back-to-original-position) solution is to **store the values you replace**, then later animate back to those. **However this assumes that the default state has not changed. What if has?**

Example:

```
   <style>
       #foo { width: 100px;overflow:hidden; }
       @media all and (min-width:600px) {
           #foo { width: 200px; }
       }
   </style>
   <div id='#foo'>bar</div>

   <script>
   // at some point use clicks a toggle
   jQuery('#foo').animate({width:0});
   // now user resizes window, triggering change in (overridden) CSS style
   // ...
   // at some later point user clicks toggle again
   jQuery('#foo').animate( **something to remove inline style** );
   </script>
```

In this example, let's say the user starts with a small browser window. The size of `#foo` is 100px. They click the toggle and it animates down to 0. Next the user resizes their window, to >600px, activating the responsive class styles which would have `#foo` at 200px. **How can I tell jQuery to figure this out and animate to it?**

### Simplified example

```
<style>
    .c { width: 50%; }
</style>
<div class='c' style='width:10%' >foo</div>
```

Given the above, how to use jQuery to find the 50% width defined for foo by its classes, ignoring the overridden style attribute?

Comment: Why would the default state change? Are you referring to the re-sizing of a window?

Comment: @F4r-20 yes, that's correct.

Comment: Well you could just make a check every time the window is changed.

Comment: @F4r-20 yes, I could trigger an event on every resize, program the media queries in as js, but it still leaves the same problem: when a style override is applied how to get the properties that have been overridden?

Answer (score 2):

Interesting problem.

There does not appear to be a way to roll back changes applied via jquery.  However, you might be able to work around this issue as you are applying the changes to the style attribute of the element.

```
$('foo').removeAttr('style');
```

See the fiddle at - http://jsfiddle.net/bG2ty/1/.

However, note that this of-course will remove any other css defined in the style attribute.

Comment: this will remove all inline styles but it will not animate

Comment: ooh, thanks, this has given me an idea...(goes away to test...)

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is using data attributes to 'remember' your width

```
<div class='c' style='width:10%' data-desktop-width="500" data-tablet-width="200">foo</div>
```

doing so you can check for the browser width and grab the correct width from the data attribute. however this is not ideal since you will have to define a lot of extra markup and if you need this kind of behavior on alot of elements, it will be very cumbersome

I personally can't think of any better way to do this. If you can live without animating it will be easier since you can just remove the style attribute all together to reset the inline styles.

EDIT: another way is maybe to animate the container to 0 and when you need to animate back, you can get the width of the element in question then animate the container back to that width. This would mean you need an extra container on each element you want to animate

http://jsfiddle.net/SS638/

Answer (score 0):

With massive credit to Kami for the key ingredient:

It seems to work to

1. Copy the style attribute.
2. unset the style attribute.
3. use jQuery to obtain any metrics needed (e.g. width)
4. re-set the style attribute
5. animate to the values obtained in step (3).
6. finally, use a `complete` callback to unset the styles that are no longer needed once we've animated back to the correct plain CSS positioning.

It seems that steps 2-4 happen so fast that the browser doens't bother rendering. (at least mine doesn't)

e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/EFGRs/

First click the "Make wide" button. the bar animates bigger. Then you can click Default to animate back to the original state, **or** click "Toggle state" *then* "Default" and it will animate back to the 2nd state. At the end, all inline styles are removed so "toggle state" will jump back and forth as normal.